# Python: reindex an array with negative index

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I have an array:

```
array[5,6,7,8,9]
```

can I reindex the array from -2 to 2, such that:

```
array[-2] = 5
array[-1] = 6
array[0] = 7
array[1] = 8
array[2] = 9
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't make the index `array[-2]` point to the number 5 if it's not actually at this position. You could create a new _list_ that'd have its elements arranged the way you want.

Comment: may I ask Why specificaly you want to arange like this?

Comment: @SunimalS.KMalkakulage mainly for the plotting purpose

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer, if it helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your array, using [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(5, 10)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [3]: np.roll(x, -2)
Out[3]: array([7, 8, 9, 5, 6])
```